# Erro Ruby após atualizar ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby, ubuntu, atualização

Após fazer a atualização do Ubuntu, o mesmo não carrega mais o Ruby ou algo assim, a mensagm de erro que retorna é:

> /usr/bin/env: “ruby2.1”: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado

Toda a vez que tenho que iniciar a aplicação

Comment: já tentou reinstalar o ruby, ou verificar a versão do ruby? pode ser q na atualização do sistema instalou a versão 2.3

Comment: O que o sistema retorna quando você digita 
$ `ruby` ?

Comment: Eu acho que o melhor a fazer é abrir o terminal  e fazer um `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove ruby ` ou um `sudo apt-get --purge remove ruby` a diferença apenas é que o `autoremove` desinstala também as dependências enquanto o `remove` não. Corrijam-me caso esteja enganado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente consegui resolver o problema clicando em Editar->Preferências do Perfil->Comando -> Executar comando como Shell de sessão -> Reiniciar terminal

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se a versão 2.1 do Ruby encontra-se instalada usando `dpkg -l ruby2.1` (deve ter um `ii` do lado esquerdo) ou mesmo se está no PATH com `which ruby2.1` (deverá retornar `/usr/bin/ruby2.1`). Se os dois testes derem positivo, então a aplicação que você está usando que pode estar procurando pelo Ruby em outro canto, talvez ela esteja usando rbenv para selecionar a versão do interpretador.